# Swipe on left panel not working

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

H, I am using Framework7 version 1.4.2, Swipe on left panel is not working for me, I am using material theme in Nexus 5 running Android Marshmallow.
I have set up the app as given below:

```
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
 material: true,
 domCache: true,
 uniqueHistory:true,
 swipeBackPage:false,
 swipePanel:“left”,
 swipePanelCloseOpposite:false,
 swipePanelOnlyClose:false,
});
```

Have anyone got it working, if yes, than what i might be doing wrong. help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My configuration was incorrect, that is why it was not working for me. The correct way to initialize is given below.

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
 material: true,
 swipeBackPage:false,
 swipePanel:"left",
 swipePanelCloseOpposite:false,
 swipePanelOnlyClose:false
});

var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
 domCache: true,
 uniqueHistory:true
});
```